# Failure during running dnf install

Tags: docker, grafana, k6

I am trying to build docker image having fedora as base image.
And trying to install grafana/k6 inside the image, using the command mentioned in doc page:
https://k6.io/docs/get-started/installation/#fedora-centos

Operation is getting aborted, without any specific error. Below are the logs:
[image]

Not sure why it got aborted. Any idea how to fix this?

Below is my docker file content:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dnf is waiting for you to tell it whether you should proceed or not with that `Is this ok [y/N]:` line near the end.

As docker does not have any tty open dnf can only take this as there is nothing that it can actually read.

Given that in this case you want to always install this you can add `-y` to both dnf commands which will tell it to just answer `y` on all question it will ask you otherwise.